# Getting getElementsByClassName with vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to get the category of a product page from amazon.

For example I am trying to get `Schaumstoffmatratzen` from the following [page](https://www.amazon.de/MSS-100700-200-90-11-Active-Matratze-Bezug/dp/B00JGTI4OU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1473316720&sr=8-1&keywords=matratze).

I am using the following libraries:

[image]

I tried the following:

```
Dim categorieAmzn
Set Docx = Ie.document

categorieAmzn = Docx.getElementsByClassName("cat-name").innerText
```

However, I get nothing back. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: It should work, span with id `cat-name` is there. Post your complete code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is more code that navigates to the webpage, the only issue with your code is that you are trying to obtain the `innerText` from an element collection, not a single element.

`getElementsbyClassName()` always obtains an element collection. In order to get a single element from the collection you will need to specify an index number but it's worth noting that index numbers start at 0 not 1. So for example, if the element you want to get is the first element with the class name of "cat-name" you should use:

```
categorieAmzn = Docx.getElementsByClassName("cat-name")(0).innerText
```

The best way to tell if you are getting a collection or a single element is by looking for an 's' in the function, if there is an 's' you will be getting a collection, if there isn't an 's' you are getting a single element.

Single HTML element function:

- `getElementbyId`

HTML Element collection functions:

- `getElementsbyClassName`
- `getElementsbyTagName`
- `getElementsbyName`